# Should hyphenation be used with noun-adverb pairs ("ear-piercingly loud") or adverb-adjective pairs ("not so-silent night")?

Tags: adverbs, hyphenation

Hyphenation is used in English in order to clear any confusion in a phrase or sentence. However, hyphens should not be used with '-ly' adverbs or 'very', so: "The **finely tuned** engine is roaring."

My question is: What if  instead of: (**-ly adverb + past participle**) formula  we have a **(noun+adverb)** formula? For example, "That noise was **ear piercingly** loud!" Should we use a hyphen between 'ear' and 'piercingly'? My grammatical sense tells me so because 'noun+adverb' is a very weird sight to me.

Further, would you extend the same rule of non-hyphenation for "very" to the adverb "so"? Meaning, would you write the following phrase with a hyphen or not, "The not so/(very) silent night?"

I'm very conflicted about adding hyphens or not.  A detailed answer is very much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this post will be downvoted because it tries to address 3 different topics. You should have submitted separate questions. To address the first one - I would use hyphens in both 'ear-piercingly' and 'not-so-silent'.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll edit my post now. Do you mind clarifying your answers more?

Comment: I think your question is fine as it is

Comment: I'm not aware of a formal rule; my instinct tells me that hyphens are needed in those phrases.

Comment: The compound premodifier-of-adjective _ear-piercingly_ is obviously formed from the compound adjective _ear-piercing_, which Collins gives as mandatorily hyphenated (do not confuse with the practice _ear piercing_). Most dictionaries demand the hyphen in _earth-shattering_,  while _heartwarming / heart-warming_ is optionally solid. // _The not-very-silent night_ is unusual, tongue-in-cheek, quirky even; the acceptability of the hyphens is a secondary issue when it comes to acceptability. I'd use these expressions (complete with hyphens) in informal registers; they're rare, so no real rules.

Comment: It probably helps to give a complete sentence as an example, rather than something like "The not so/(very) silent night?" which isn't very clear. Generally a hyphen is unnecessary with "so" or "not so" but in specific examples, it may change. You may be looking for a general rule but it's rare that you can say something is the case 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

According to [grammarbook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp)

> Rule 1. Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective.
>
> **Examples**:
> an off-campus apartment
> state-of-the-art design
>
> When a compound adjective follows a noun, a hyphen is usually not necessary.
>
> **Example**: The apartment is off campus.
>
> However, some established compound adjectives are always hyphenated. Double-check with a dictionary or online.
>
> **Example**: The design is state-of-the-art.

Therefore one should hyphenate it.

Answer (score 0):

The compound premodifier-of-adjective *ear-piercingly* is obviously formed from the compound adjective *ear-piercing*, which Collins gives as mandatorily hyphenated (do not confuse with the practice ear piercing).

Most dictionaries demand the hyphen in *earth-shattering* (though both hyphenated and open compound forms are commonly used predicatively on the internet, for example *the diagnosis was earth shattering / earth-shattering*).

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/earthshakers) allows *earthshaking* as well as *earth-shaking*, and
*heartwarming* / *heart-warming* is also optionally solid.

So there appears to be no convenient rule to follow here. Obviously, some solid forms will be resisted, and some open forms don't seem too natural; I'd stick with 'mind-blowing / mind-blowingly [spectacular]'. Preferred forms are often found in dictionaries, though rarer compounds will not be.

...............

[In response to the now-deleted query about multiply hyphenated novel premodifiers]:

The example

- *a not-very-silent night*

is unusual, tongue-in-cheek, quirky even; the acceptability of the hyphens is a secondary issue when it comes to acceptability. I'd use these expressions (complete with hyphens) in informal registers; they're rare, so no really authoritative rules. But using hyphens to show what the multi-word lexemes actually comprise seems logical (and less messy and less ambiguous than using square brackets, a [not very silent] night, say).